# Hide jQuery Mobile fixed toolbars on orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation

Using jQuery Mobile I can create a fixed toobar on a page using:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">Content</div>
```

What I'd like to do would be to hide the fixed header when the device orientation changes, I can detect this using:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange ', function() {
    if (event.orientation === 'portrait') {

    }
    else if (event.orientation === 'landscape') {
    }
});
```

How can I hide the fixedtoolbar from the page? Setting `display: none` on the toolbar works, but leaves an empty space where the header was previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/d2mMv/

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#test-header').hide();
    $('#test-content').addClass('test-content');
});
```

CSS:

```
.test-content {
    margin-top: -40px !important;
}
```

Unfortunately because we are hiding a header it still exist so we can trigger **create**, **pagecreate** or **updatelayout**, thus we need to do it manually with css.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it really helped. In the end I decided to toggle hide-fixed-header class when in landscape. Then used this css to hide the header
`.hide-fixed-header { margin-top: -46px !important; }
.hide-fixed-header .header { display: none; }`